# Magento2 Admin login is coming blank

Tags: magento2

Installation of Magento2 went fine, but when i try to access the admin page, it gives me blank login screen.

pub/static has generated css,js correctly for frontend and adminhtml

I see problem with the body section being empty.

When i checked log it is showing this error

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: C:\wamp\www\magento2-develop\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml
```

So the templates are not getting correctly linked,

I have deployed Magento2 on WAMP.

Comment: Please clear your cache.
Go to your magento 2 root directory and run the below command in console.

php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is broken from the past Friday: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2077#issuecomment-147187281

Comment: please don't add single link answers. Even if they might solve the problem, what's on the other side of the link can be gone anytime. Please add your solution in here also. Do the same for your other answers please.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks you saved my day, this is bit frustrating to work on buggy git release of Magento2